# I have a map view with annotations that enters on the users location. But it keeps snapping back after panning and zooming

Tags: swift, swiftui, location, mapkit

So I have a an with multiple views that work well (I think!) but here I have a tabview that inherits from a navigation view.

One of the views is a map view. I want it to show markers pinpointing the location of items in an array. The array is fetched from core data. This bit works.
I also want it to be centered on the users location. This works too.
However it won't let the user zoom or pan. If they do it then works for about a second and then snaps back.

I don't understand what's happening. I am getting warnings that number in the hundreds from Xcode :

My Treasures[47973:31992817] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.

However it doesn't say where this is - it just displays in on the @main. So I can't debug it.

It only appears when I'm on the map view. Please help. I can't work out what's going wrong and I'm losing my mind.

Thank you

MapView2:

```
import CoreData
import CoreLocation
import Foundation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct MapView2: View {
    let locationFetcher = LocationFetcher()
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)]) var allFinds: FetchedResults<Finds>
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "Nature Find")) var natureFinds: FetchedResults<Finds>
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "Man-made Find")) var manMadeFind: FetchedResults<Finds>
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "Things I Made")) var thingsIMade: FetchedResults<Finds>
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "Others")) var others: FetchedResults<Finds>
    
    @StateObject var manager = LocationManager()
    
//    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55, longitude: -3), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))
    
    
    @State private var showingFilter = false
    
    enum FilterType {
        case none, NatureFind, ManMadFind, ThingsMade, Others
    }
    
    @State private var selection =  FilterType.none
    @State private var findsArray: FetchedResults<Finds>?
    
    @State private var colorType = Color.green
    
    
    var filterOn: Bool {
        if selection == .none {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
            
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //            NavigationView {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $manager.region, interactionModes: .all, annotationItems: filterOn ? findsArray! : allFinds) { location in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.lat, longitude: location.long)) {
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(find: location)
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(colorType)
                                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                                .overlay {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(.black)
                                        .frame(width: 10)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        showingFilter = true
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: filterOn ? "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill" : "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .padding(30)
                    }.offset(y: -70)
                    
                }
            }.confirmationDialog("Choose filter option", isPresented: $showingFilter) {
                Button("None") { selection = FilterType.none}
                Button("Nature Finds") { selection = FilterType.NatureFind }
                Button("Man-made Finds") { selection = FilterType.ManMadFind }
                Button("Things I Made") { selection = FilterType.ThingsMade }
                Button("Others") { selection = FilterType.Others }
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
            } message: {
                Text("Choose a filter")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            findsArray = allFinds
            
        }
        .onChange(of: selection) { newValue in
            
            findsArray = filteredFinds(filter: newValue)
            colorType = setColorType(filter: newValue)
        }
        
    }

    func filteredFinds(filter: FilterType) -> FetchedResults<Finds> {
        switch(filter) {
        case .none:
            return allFinds
        case .ManMadFind:
            return manMadeFind
        case .NatureFind:
            return natureFinds
        case .ThingsMade:
            return thingsIMade
        case .Others:
            return others
        }
    }
    
    func setColorType(filter: FilterType) -> Color {
        switch(filter) {
        case .none:
            return .green
        case .ManMadFind:
            return .yellow
        case .NatureFind:
            return .mint
        case .ThingsMade:
            return .pink
        case .Others:
            return .blue
        }
    }
    
}

struct MapView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView2()
    }
}
```

Location Manager:

```
//
//  LocationManager.swift
//  My Treasures
//
//  Created by Layth Tameem on 04/11/2022.
//

import CoreLocation
import Foundation
import MapKit

class LocationManager: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {

    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
            super.init()
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        
        if let lastKnownLocation = locations.last?.coordinate {
            
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: lastKnownLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried lots of online videos that show how to do this, there's clearly different ways but still, neither works....

Answer (score 2):

So I fixed the issue with the map snapping back.

Instead of the map region reading form location manager I got the app to read the location of the user on the start screen of the app. It then help this location and placed it into the environment.

I then changed the region so that it was set to an @State private var region and used an initialiser to give this an initial value. The initial value used the coordinates pass to it from the previous view. Now it starts with the initial region as the users location but will pan and zoom as needed.

the constant error message seems to be a bug with Xcode 14.1 and map annotations. I've subsequently discovered lots of people have this. [It is discussed here](https://www.donnywals.com/xcode-14-publishing-changes-from-within-view-updates-is-not-allowed-this-will-cause-undefined-behavior/)

Hope that helps anyone else.